# Make wx.BusyInfo stay on top in wxpython

Tags: python, dialog, wxpython

Using the below example, how do I make wx.BusyInfo stay on top of everything, even if I open another application?

```
import time
import wx

########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY,
                          "BusyDialog Tutorial")
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        busyBtn = wx.Button(panel, label="Show Busy Dialog")
        busyBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onBusy)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(busyBtn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onBusy(self, event):
        self.Hide()
        msg = "Please wait while we process your request..."
        busyDlg = wx.BusyInfo(msg)
        time.sleep(5)
        busyDlg = None
        self.Show()

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: From document http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_busy_info.html `Note that a wxBusyInfo is always built with the wxSTAY_ON_TOP window style`

Answer (score 0):

According to [Robin Dunn](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/PU7Mae-FjBM):

> The frame used by wx.BusyInfo only uses the stay on top flag if the 
>   parent window also has it.

---

```
def onBusy(self, event):
    self.Hide()
    msg = "Please wait while we process your request..."
    old_style = self.GetWindowStyle()
    self.SetWindowStyle(old_style | wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
    busyDlg = wx.BusyInfo(msg, self)
    time.sleep(5)
    busyDlg = None
    self.Show()
    self.SetWindowStyle(old_style)
```

Comment: This still doesn't work, if I open another window or app it opens over the top of this.

Comment: wx.STAY_ON_TOP only applies to your wx application. There is no way for an application to be on top of everything else unless you have hooks into the OS itself...the only application I know of that can stay on top of everything else was Microsoft's Task Manager.